# Change default pom.xml and project layout of Maven

Tags: maven

I am just starting using maven and I use Apache Maven Shade Plugin a lot. Is it possible to add these code

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <!-- put your configurations here -->
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

to default pom.xml. Yes, it can change setting.xml to make this plugin work with all project. But if I have some specific project which will not need this plugin, do I have to rewrite setting.xml again?

Another problem is that is it possible to change project layout of Maven. I use git a lot. Can I add sample .gitignore every time when I run `mvn archetype:generate`.

Comment: First you should start using the plugin where it is needed. To define some kind of default it's best to create a company-pom which contains versions and default configuration for your projects. What do you mean by `..I have to rewrite settings.xml again?` cause settings.xml file is intended to hold only configuration for repositories and may be some credentials but nothing project specific, cause this belongs to the pom file. Apart from that changing the project layout does not make sense only if you  have really really special requirements if this is true you should think about using Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you first issue, I think you can benefit from the `parent POM`:

http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-parent.html

It's a defined POM file in which you put whatever you want. You publish it as a "pom" in your Maven repository and then, you can inherit from it in other projects. It is very convenient to lock dependency verions as well.

Your second issue seems more related to the archetype you are using than maven itself. You will probably have to create your own with a default .gitignore in it.